# Check validity of multiple forms with vuetify watch option?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, watch

I have a button on a page that should be disabled unless every form on the page is considered 'valid' via lazy-validation. Say I have three forms with the following v-model props: 'contactValid, 'addressValid' and 'infoValid'. I want something to watch if any of the props change from true to false, and if any are false to disable the button. The data and condition would look something like this:

```
data: () => ({
  formsValid: false,
  contactValid: false,
  addressValid: false,
  infoValid: false,
})

if (contactValid && addressValid && infoValid){
 infoValid = true;
}
```

How can I use watch to accomplish this? Or do I need to do this another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a computed property.

```html
<button :disabled='shouldDisable'>Hello</button>
```

```js
computed: {
   shouldDisable() {
      return !this.contactValid || !this.addressValid || !this.infoValid;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use vue computed property:

```
  data: () => ({
     infoValid: false,
     contactValid: false,
     addressValid: false
  }),
  computed: {
     formsValid() {
       if (this.infoValid && this.contactValid && this.addressValid){
         return true;
       }
       return false;
     },
  }
```